# PHP create function Palindrome

Tags: php, arrays, palindrome

I really need your help. I have to create a function that takes 2 positive integers as its arguments and returns the numerical palindromes as an array of n numerical palindromes that come after the num, including num. Also, single-digit numbers are not considered numerical palindromes. So the outcome must be like this --> function(4,6) // returns [11,22,33,44]. Function(4, 6) it's an array that will take only 4 elements and the numerical palindromes must be greater than 6. Other examples are function (1, 75) // returns [77] and function (3, 100) // returns [101, 111, 121]
My code so far:

```
<?php

function createPalindrome($input)
{
    $m = $input;
    $palin = $input;
    while ($m > 1) {
       $d = intval($m % 10);
       $palin = $palin * 10 + $d;
       $m = intval($m / 10);
    }
return $palin;
}

function generatePalindromes($x, $n)
{
    $arr = [];
    $i = 1;
    while (($number = createPalindrome($i)) <= $n) {
        $arr[] = $number;
        $i++;
    }
    for($j = 0; $j < $x; $j++)
        var_dump($arr[$j]);
}


generatePalindromes(4, 77);
```

The outcome is:
int(1)
int(22)
int(33)
int(44)

Comment: I don't understand the requirements. Why does `(4, 6)` translate to `[11,22,33,44]`?

Comment: Because it's an array that will take only 4 elements and the numerical palindromes must be greater than 6. Other examples are function (1, 75) // returns [77] and function (3, 100) // returns [101, 111, 121]

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Create `n` palindrome numbers greater than `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Had to modify this answer a fair bit once Giann49 expounded on his question in a comment reply.

This is not the cleanest or most precise way to do this for sure but it will principally function and hopefully help point you in the right direction logically.

```
function findExceedingPalindromes($palindromeLimit,$startingPoint){
   $palindromesFound = 0; //Set an initial counter for number of palindromes found so far.
   $palindromeSet = []; //Create an array to contain all the palindromes.

   if($palindromeLimit <= 0 || $startingPoint <= 0){ //Both integers need to be positive as stated.
       return false; //If they aren't return false. You can return whatever you want to halt execution of the function. This is just an easy example.
   }

   if($startingPoint < 10){
      $startingPoint = 10; //Since single digits aren't valid if the starting number if less than 10 kick it up to 10.
   }

   while($palindromesFound <= $palindromeLimit){
      $startingPoint++; //Since the first palindrome must exceed the starting point increment it up once at the top of the loop.

      $reverseNumber = strrev($startingPoint); //reverse the current number.
    
      if($startingPoint === $reverseNumber){
          array_push($palindromeSet,$startingPoint);
          $palindomresFound++; //If we find a palindome move the number found 1 higher.
      }
    }

   return $palindromeSet;
}
```

As an explanation.

The first argument is the number of palindromes to generate. The second argument is the number we want to start palindrome generation at then work up from there.

We create two variables. One is to track how many palindromes have been found. The other is an empty array to insert found palindromes into.

You say the two numbers must be positive integers so if they are anything less than  1 we'll want to exit the function. (optional)

You say single digits don't count so if the starting point is less than 10 we'll just move it up to 10 for starters. (optional)

Now we'll start a while loop. While the number of palindromes is less than the number we want to find the loop will keep running.

We add 1 to the starting point right out of the gate because we want to first palindrome to be higher than the starting point if it already is one. As in if 11 is the number set as the point to start searching we want to look at 11 + 1 for starters. (optional)

To check if a number of a palindrome we want to simply reverse it's string. If the strings are the same forward and back obviously it matches the definition of a palindrome. So we'll add that number into the set of found palindromes and move the number found 1 digit higher.

Once the requested number of palindromes are found we'll break the while loop and return the array of what was found.

Comment: Function (4,6) it's an array that will take only 4 elements and the numerical palindromes must be greater than 6. Other examples are function (1, 75) // returns [77] and function (3, 100) // returns [101, 111, 121]. Sorry it was my fault I didn't explained it more. But thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: I updated my comment to hopefully give you something you can better work with.

Comment: This works just fine. It only might become inefficient when encountering very large numbers (because then palindromes might be far apart and it would require millions of iterations to get to the next one). I know that you're aware this algorithm has its shortcomings (as you state at the beginning of your answer), I just wanted to point out the exact situation when this would be an issue for any future readers.